# Sending Post Data with a Number

Tags: php, mysql, post, input

I have a page with 100 checkboxes.. on and off. These checkboxes are named "box1" "box2" "box3" etc. They are pulled from a single row/col in a table where I exploded 1|0|1|0|1 into individual checkbox inputs.

My issue is that when I try to update them, I can't figure out how I can get them back into a single string to put them back into the same column. Here is what I have.. but clearly it doesn't work. Some of this stuff is new to me. Any advice would help.

```
$i = 1;
while($i < 101){
    $thisBox = $_POST['box'][$i];
    if($thisBox != 1){$thisBox = 0;}
    $boxData .= $thisBox . "|";
    $i++;
}
```

It just shows up with 100x "|" and I am unsure if it's possible to create the `$_POST['box##']` with each loop.

Comment: Please post the html for this. Need to see what boxes post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$thisBox = $_POST['box'.$i]`

Comment: I cannot believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much. That worked. I'll accept as an answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$thisBox = $_POST["box$i"] == "on" ? 1 : 0;
$boxData .= $thisBox . "|";
```

No need of `if` condition